# Request timeout error (H12) on Heroku deployment for website scraping and Excel generation

Tags: python, heroku

I have developed a website that scrapes data from a webpage, processes it, saves it into an Excel file, and then sends the file as an attachment. On my local machine, the whole process completes successfully in around 45 to 50 seconds without any errors. However, when I deploy the application on Heroku, I encounter a "Request timeout" error (H12) after 30 seconds of processing. Despite the error, the code doesn't throw any exceptions on my local machine.

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/process" host=nasdaq-py-34f53a3cf504.herokuapp.com request_id=b924348a-0bc2-4d6f-9399-6be52a899d7d fwd="182.190.222.106" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

How can I resolve this "Request timeout" error (H12) on Heroku and ensure the application completes the process successfully within the specified time frame?

Comment: Not too familiar with Heroku, but have you considered using AWS Batch which runs on AWS Fargate?